# Fastest way to flip multiline text in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for the shortest line of unobfuscated code to reverse multiline strings in jquery. For example,

> abcd
>
> edfg
>
> hijk

should become

> dcba
>
> gfde
>
> kjih

An extremely complicated example would look like:

```
function fliptext() {
    var text = document.getElementById('input_output').value;
    text = text.replace(/\r/gi, '');
    text = text.replace(/([^a-z 0-9\n])/gi, ' $1 ');
    text = text.split('\n').reverse().join('\n');
    text = text.split('').reverse().join('');
    text = text.replace(/ ([^a-z 0-9\n]) /gi, '$1');
    document.getElementById('input_output').value = text;
}
```

What's a better way?

Answer (score 4):

You could do;

```
text = text.split('\n').map(function(el) {return el.split('').reverse().join('')}).join('\n');
```

First, we split the text by newlines and get an array of lines, then reverse every line, then join the array with a newline ('\n') and get a string.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `el.split('').reverse()`?

Comment: @keune This is the same as writing `text.split('').reverse().join('')`

Comment: well that makes sense, since it's a string, there's no need to go over every line.

Comment: @keune And will not support `text = "abc\ndef"` because you would make it to `"fed\ncba"` where OP wants `"cba\nfed"`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the shortest one:

```
var text = "abcdef\n123\n789";
text = text.split('').reverse().join('').split("\n").reverse().join("\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var el = document.getElementById('input_output');
var value = el.value;
// Split on newline and iterate over each line 
//   this will preserve the the line numbers.
var output = value.split('\n').map(function(line) {
  // Split on each character this will create an array
  //   like this: "abc" -> ["a", "b", "c"]
  //   .reverse() will reverse the array -> ["c", "b", "a"]
  //   .join will make the array a string again.
  return line.split('').reverse().join('');
}).join('\n');
```

Answer (score -2):

CSS:

```
.flipped {
    transform: scale(-1, 1);
}
```

jQuery:

```
$("#some_div").addClass("flipped");
```

Comment: That would be a nice joke/loophole for PPCG. That one does flip an element, but it doesn't flip the value/innerHTML. Which both these may be a use-case for that code.